# JavaFX Scene Builder, multiple ImageViews with the same image

Tags: performance, javafx, imageview, fxml, scenebuilder

I have placed a few image views to the scene, all pointing to the same image with different 
viewports.

**generated fxml:**

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
    <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="80.0" layoutY="91.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
        <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../Pictures/sas.png" />
        </image>
        <viewport>
            <Rectangle2D height="50.0" minY="50.0" width="50.0" />
        </viewport>
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="308.0" layoutY="91.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
        <viewport>
            <Rectangle2D height="50.0" minX="50.0" minY="50.0" width="50.0" />
        </viewport>
        <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../Pictures/sas.png" />
        </image>
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView layoutX="225.0" layoutY="250.0">
        <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../Pictures/sas.png" />
        </image>
    </ImageView>
</children>
```

Question is, will this create 3 instances of the same image in memory?
If yes, then what is the best ways to avoid it, url("") in style attribute, css class? I would like to avoid creating css class for each individual icon!

Is it even worth using single large croped image for multiple icons & UI elements instead of small image for each at this day & age?

Answer (score 2):

A quick test shows that the `ImageView`s do not reference the same `Image` in memory.

To do so, you can either used css as you described, or you can define the `Image` once in the FXML with an `<fx:define>` block and reference it via its `fx:id` attribute:

```
<fx:define>
    <Image url="@../../../../../Pictures/sas.png" fx:id="sasImage" />
</fx:define>
<ImageView image="$sasImage" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="80.0" layoutY="91.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
    <viewport>
        <Rectangle2D height="50.0" minY="50.0" width="50.0" />
    </viewport>
</ImageView>
<ImageView image="$sasImage" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="308.0" layoutY="91.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
    <viewport>
        <Rectangle2D height="50.0" minX="50.0" minY="50.0" width="50.0" />
    </viewport>
</ImageView>
<ImageView image="$sasImage" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="250.0">
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Ah, I answered in terms of FXML: I'm not sure if SceneBuilder supports `<fx:define>`.

Comment: Problem is it makes file unreadable by scenebuilder, which can be tedious in large projects. So sticking to CSS is probably the right way.

Comment: The one disadvantage of the css approach is that it doesn't set the `image` property on the `ImageView`. So if you needed to retrieve the image later in the controller with `ImageView.getImage()` you wouldn't be able to; the `<fx:define>` approach allows this. It's probably worth filing a [feature request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) for `<fx:define>` support in SceneBuilder.